# Trigger on extended properties? SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, triggers, extended-properties

Does SQL Server allow triggers on extended properties, table level or column level?

If not, is there anything like a trigger that can detect an 'add' or 'update' on extended properties and execute a stored procedure automatically?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a DDL trigger for this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo
ON DATABASE
FOR CREATE_EXTENDED_PROPERTY, ALTER_EXTENDED_PROPERTY
AS
  BEGIN
      /*TODO: Something useful here*/
      SELECT EVENTDATA()
  END
```

Comment: @Brian - RE your comment on the now deleted answer these specific events exist as far back as SQL Server 2008. I don't have 2005 to test.